# Validation of Date in C# with correct Error Messages

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to validate only the Date of a DateTime by using .NET CORE MVC 2.1! I have several problems during this validation process. Here you can see my code:

```
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please insert a date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date,ErrorMessage ="Insert value is not a valide date")]
        [Range(typeof(DateTime), "01.01.2000", "01.01.2100",ErrorMessage = "Date should be between {1} and {2} .")]
        public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
```

I used the following annotations and in the frontend i used the following lines of code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.MyDate)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.MyDate)
```

Here is my code for the HTTP POST:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(TestModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Of course i also validate the ModelState in the Controller. It all works, but still have this problems:

1. Given error messages aren't shown. For example see point 3
2. Every valid date like 01.01.2000 or 2000.01.01 or 08/08/2020 is allowed. But i only want to allow this format (dd.MM.yyyy)!
3. If i insert a wrong date like 32.32.1999 this message is shown: *The value '32.32.1999'is not valid for MyDate*. But i would like to show: *Insert value is not a valide date.*

How could i fix it? Where are my problems?

Comment: Please show your c# code about the post function , the codes works on my side .

Comment: @NanYu i updatet the section